# Nlog archive file name: iteration instead valid date

Tags: .net, nlog

My configuration:

```
    <target xsi:type="File"
        name="default"
        archiveAboveSize="10000000"
        layout="${VerboseLayout}"
        fileName="${basedir}/logs/Log_${shortdate}.log"
        keepFileOpen="false"
        archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/Log_${shortdate}.{##}.log"
        archiveNumbering="Sequence"
        archiveEvery="Day"
        maxArchiveFiles="50" />
```

Sometimes naming is ok, sometimes instead of valid date I get date+1 and iteration (like in case of reach archiveAboveSize cap).
My last files:

```
Log_2018-01-15.log
Log_2018-01-15.00.log (should be Log_2018-01-14)
Log_2018-01-13.log
Log_2018-01-13.00.log (should be Log_2018-01-12)
Log_2018-01-11.log
Log_2018-01-10.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the NLog file archive logic wrong:

```
fileName="${basedir}/logs/Log_${shortdate}.log"
archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/Log_${shortdate}.{##}.log"
archiveEvery="Day"
```

You should not specify the **${shortdate}** for the `archiveFileName`. It will use current time, instead of the time of the previous logevent (which you are expecting).

You should not specify `archiveEvery="Day"` as fileName already includes `${shortdate}`, so it will automatically roll to new file.

Instead you should do it like this, when using NLog 4.4 or older:

```
fileName="${basedir}/logs/Log_${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/Log_{##}.log"
archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
archiveAboveSize="10000000"
archiveEvery="Year"
maxArchiveFiles="50"
```

- **archiveFileName** - Using {#} allows the archive cleanup to generate proper file wildcard.
- **archiveDateFormat** - Must match the ${date:format=} of the fileName (So remember to correct both date-formats, if change is needed)
- **archiveNumbering=DateAndSequence** - Configures the archive cleanup to support parsing of filenames as dates and sequence number
- **archiveEvery=Year** - Activates the archive cleanup, but also the archive file operation. Because the configured fileName automatically ensures the archive file operation, then we don't want any additional archive operations (Ex. avoiding generating extra empty files at midnight).
- **maxArchiveFiles** - How many archive files to keep around.

When using NLog 4.5 (or newer), then the following should work:

```
fileName="${basedir}/logs/Log_${shortdate}.log"
archiveAboveSize="10000000"
maxArchiveFiles="50"
```